# Adding a new item in options with dropdown_search package doesn't rebuild the popup

Tags: flutter, get, state-management

I'm currently using [dropdown_search](https://stackoverflow.com) in projet with [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for the state management.

I would like to add a new item in the `items` property after a user input. My logic works but the problem is my view for the popup associated with the `DropdownSearch` widget doesn't reduild itself, I need to close then reopen it for the change to operate.

Here is my code for the view :

```dart
Obx(() => DropdownSearch<String>.multiSelection(
  key: cAliment.dropdownKey,
  // Here
  items: cAliment.brands.value,
  selectedItems: cAliment.selectedBrands,
  popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.modalBottomSheet(
    showSelectedItems: true,
    showSearchBox: true,
    searchDelay: Duration.zero,
    validationWidgetBuilder: (_, __) =>
      const SizedBox.shrink(),
    onDismissed: () => cAliment.updateBrands(),
    searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => cAliment.openDialogAddBrand(
            dialog: DialogSingleInputForm(
              title: DialogTexts.addBrand,
              formKey: cAliment.newBrandFormKey,
              inputName: FormKeys.brands,
              initialValue: null,
              validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                FormBuilderValidators.required(),
              ]),
              valueTransformer: null,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              onCancelClick: () => cAliment.goBack(),
              onOKClick: () => cAliment.addNewBrand(),
            ),
          ),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
    dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: InputTexts.brands,
    ),
  ),
)),
```

I can give more code if necessary.

Thank you for your help.